# How can I have a user save and load their game in my text-based rpg in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python

I'm making a text-based rpg, but can't think of any way to have a user save their progress and load it back up. Any thoughts?

I'm a new programmer, and I haven't done much research, except for on this site. I thought about writing and reading to and from a text file, but that didn't work.

Comment: first `open(..., "w")`, `write(...)`, `close()`, then `open(..., "r")`, `read()`, `close()`. But there are other formats to read/write data - json, yaml, ini, pickle, sqlite, etc. They can be easier to use.

Comment: Why is this tagged `python` but your question title states `Visual Studio`?? Which are you going for?

Comment: "I thought about writing and reading to and from a text file, but that didn't work." -- how so? That is a natural approach which is very, very easy to do in Python. If you want help with your code, you need to show it.

Comment: @Reedinationer Visual Studio Code is the code editor that I use to write my python. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @JohnColeman I thought about writing every line of text into a text file and then opening that up when it was to be used again but I realized that it would... actually now that I'm thinking about it more closely I can see how it could work. I fixed it and now it looks like this:

Comment: I fixed it but I don't know how to show it (I'm new here) but if someone tells me how I can show my code I will show it.

Comment: Your question isn't really answerable in any meaningful way. The mechanics of reading from and writing to text files is easy enough. Just what to read and write depends on the particulars of your game, which is completely unknown to us. It isn't clear what sort of answer you were expecting.

Comment: Perhaps you could spend some time reading the help sections such as [ask] to get help on things like how to write a good question, how to post code, etc.

Comment: To add your code you first deduce the simplest form of it (known as a MVCE as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then you copy/paste it into your post -> highlight it all -> press ctrl + k to format it into a code block within your post

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
def save(what_to_write):
  file = open("file_name.txt", "w")
  write = file.writelines(what_to_write)
  file.close()

  file = open("file_name.txt")
  cont = file.readline()
  print (cont)
  file.close()
```